# What is the best way to show animated statistics on a web application?

Tags: html, user-interface, web-applications, web

I want to develop a nice looking web application which contains a little UI, communicate with a SQL Database and is able to show animated statistics. (Something like that: http://www.awwwards.com/).

Till now, I just developed webpages using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP and have some experiences in C# and I do not know exactly how to get this fancy looking stuff on my application.

Is there maybe something existing which I can use/buy or maybe i should take into consideration further options than javascript...?

I appreciate every hint.

Answer (score 1):

You can do animations with HTML5 -- there are amazing stunning websites using only HTML5 take a look at this for example: http://animatron.com/

But there are several tools that can help you accomplish what you want - HTML5 will be more natural as any other

Good Luck!